# Reconstructing a polygon from the Midpoints of Its Sides

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, polygons

I was reading through Dijkstra's 'A Collection of Beautiful Proofs' and stumbled upon this elegant piece of work:

> **11. Reconstructing an odd polygon from the midpoints of its sides.**
>
> We shall show the construction for poly = 5.
>
> For the pentagon ABCDE , the points marked AB, BC. CD, DE, and EA
>   respectively are the midpoints of its successive sides. Given the
>   positions of those five midpoints, it is requested to reconstruct the
>   original pentagon ABCDE.
>   [...]

[Click here for a representation of the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJOmS.png) $^1$

So Dijkstra solves this problem by taking an arbitrary point $X_0$ and rotating it around $AB$, $BC$, $CD$, $DE$ and $EA$ successively, as can be seen in the image. The original point $A$ is the midpoint of the line from the resulting point $X_5$ and the intial, arbitrary point $X_0$. The position of $B$, $C$, $D$ and $E$ indeed follow trivially.

When I read this solution, I thought about other (probably less elegant) ways to reconstruct the polygon - and then how it would be possible to extent this to any arbitrary (odd) polygon.

In the case of a triangle it seems pretty simple and has been answered here already: [Is it possible to reconstruct a triangle from the midpoints of its sides?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683489/is-it-possible-to-reconstruct-a-triangle-from-the-midpoints-of-its-sides)

I am not that familiar with Mathematics and Geometry anymore, but what would be another or more general solution for the above described problem?

$^1$ Picture and excerpt taken from:
https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD05xx/EWD538.html